# Repeating contents of a file into another file using Python

Tags: python, repeat

So I am new to Python and I am trying to create a script that reads 10 lines of data from one text file and then repeats that data 1000 times and writes it to another text file.  Reading the file is not the problem, but this is what I have:

```
fr = open('TR.txt', 'r')
text = fr.read()
print(text)
fr.close()
```

Now I understand that this opens the file and prints the contents.  I just need to take those entries and repeat them 1000 times and then write those to a file.  This is what I have so far to write to a file (I know this probably doesn't make sense):

```
fw = open('TrentsRecords.txt', 'w')
fw.write(text.repeat(text, 1000000))
fw.close()
```

Comment: Just use the text multiplication operator: `"abc" * 3 == "abcabcabc"`

Comment: The first code snippet seems not "reads 10 lines of data", but read in everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = (text + '\n')*1000
fw.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import repeat,islice

fw.write("".join(repeat(text, 10000)))
```

So:

```
with open('TR.txt') as fr, open('TrentsRecords.txt', 'w') as fw:
    text = list(islice(fr, None, 10)) # get first ten lines
    fw.writelines(repeat(line.strip()+"\n", 10000)) # write first ten lines 10000 times
```

`with` will automatically close your files.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply. If it is a string, it will concatenate. If it is a number, it will multiply.

```
fw.write(text * 1000000) # add newlines if you want
```

Look at the Python Documentation. This is taken straight from it.

> Strings can be concatenated (glued together) with the `+` operator, and repeated with `*`:

```
>>> # 3 times 'un', followed by 'ium'
>>> 3 * 'un' + 'ium'
'unununium'
```